# Как сделать поиск доступных bluetooth устройств под андроид в xamarin

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, bluetooth

Смотрел статьи и ничего не смог найти, можете помочь (чтобы все имена устройств записывались в массив строк)

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;

bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

if (bluetooth != null && bluetooth.IsEnabled)
{
    List<String> device = new List<String>();
    // и здесь требуется вписать в массив строк все устройства с включенным Bluetooth поблизости
}
```

Я не имею понятия как сделать `BluetoothScanner`, который будет сканировать пространство для поиска доступных устройств. Нужен поиск новых устройств, а не уже сопряженных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как под рукой не оказалось Xamarin - пишу ответ, основываясь на документации к методам, классам и свойствам, а также основываясь на найденные ответы.

1) Необходимо получить экземпляр `BluetoothAdapter` на текущем устройстве и проверить, включен ли он

2) Необходимо получить все физические устройства, существующие как сопряженные устройства с текущим устройством, для этого нужно использовать коллекцию `BondedDevices` из полученного ранее адаптера.

Теперь код, который должен нам помочь:

```
// получить адаптер по-умолчанию
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

// проверяем, что у нас получен адаптер (есть Bluetooth) и он включен
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled)
{
    // получим список связанных устройств
    ICollection<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.BondedDevices;

    // инициализируем пустой список строк имен устройств
    List<String> names = new List<String>();

    // пройдем по списку устройств и будем заполнять список имен
    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        // device - сопряженное устройство из BondedDevices
        names.Add(device.Name); // добавление имени
    }
}
```

В дополнение к ответу добавлю код, который будет выводить в список еще и новые устройства, находящиеся рядом, для этого потребуется написать свой перегруженный метод `OnReceive` в классе, наследующем `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    // перегрузим метод `OnReceive`
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // это действие, которое будем выполнять (для нас пока будет только поиск)
        String action = intent.Action;

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            // Получить устройство
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

            // если устройство не сопряжено (его еще не было в BondedDevices)
            if (newDevice.BondState != Bond.Bonded) 
            {
                // нужно учитывать, что переменная `names` должна быть в области видимости
                names.Add(newDevice.Name); // добавление имени
            }
        }
        // далее можно описать и другое действие, к примеру остановка поиска
        // это будет action = BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished
    }
}
```

Затем, чтобы использовать написанный класс - необходим следующий код:

```
// создадим фильтр с указанным дейсвтием - поиск
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
// наш ранее описанный ресивер, для поиска по указанному фильтру
BluetoothDeviceReceiver receiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
// зарегистрируем трансляцию(ресивер) и фильтр для обнаружения устройств
RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
// запустим поиск, это тот же адаптер из `BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter`
adapter.StartDiscovery();
```

Также, чтобы не было глюков в приложении я рекомендую описать действие для `BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished` - запускается он точно так же, как и `BluetoothDevice.ActionFound`, но только позже. И не забыть освободить занятый ресурс транслятора (ресивера), через метод `UnregisterReceiver`. Дополнительный пример кода можно найти вот тут: [Bluetooth Chat `DeviceListActivity`](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.cs)

Ссылки на полезные источники:

- [How to get all available bluetooth devices android c# xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356298/5275890)
- [How do I get all the available bluetooth devices in a listview C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1199364/How-do-I-get-all-the-available-bluetooth-devices-i)
- [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter/)
- [BluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled/)
- [BluetoothDevice.Name](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.Name/)
- [BluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices/)

Comment: Я имею ввиду, чтобы в массив строк записывались имена устройств, находящихся рядом с нашим устройством (Bluetooth Scanner)

Comment: @АлексейПапков добавьте в вопрос то, что у Вас уже есть, чтобы понять более конкретно вопрос. Как будет время, внесу правку в ответ

Comment: код стайл - скобки!